# Trouble with preserving source file path

Tags: c, gcov

Assuming I'm currently in `/home/testUser/gcovTest/test1/` directory where I have a file `test.c` which I compile with `gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage test.c` which generates relevant `.gcda and .gcno` files.

After successful compilation, I execute the generated binary `./a.out` and run the following command to generate the `.gcov` report.

```
gcov -p test.c
```

#### What I expected

The resultant `test.c.gcov` file should have contained the full path of `test.c` i.e. `home/testUser/gcovTest/test1/test.c` in the `source:` tag but actually it contains just `test.c`

#### Question

How I can get gcov to preserve the complete path of `test.c` in `test.c.gcov` file?

I have even tried the follwing but it still prints `test.c` in source of `test.c.gcov`

```
gcov -p home/testUser/gcovTest/test1/test.c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-p` switch for `gcov` preserves the path of the input file *in the file name of the output*. That is,

```
gcov -p /foo/bar/baz.c
```

generates the file `#foo#bar#baz.c.gcov` instead of simply `baz.c.gcov` - but the contents of the file are identical.

The name of the source file, as shown in the `.gcov` report, is generated by `gcc`. If you wish the full path to be included in the report, simply specify the full path on your compilation command line:

```
$ gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage /foo/bar/test.c
$ ./a.out
$ gcov test.c
File '/foo/bar/test.c'
Lines executed: ...
Creating 'test.c.gcov'
$ head -n 1 test.c.gcov
        -:    0: Source:/foo/bar/test.c
```